# TextChange while updating input fields

Tags: javascript, html, json, input, knockout.js

I have two text Fields

[image]

I have two fields, which is reference and hotel id as stated on the image,

the value (valeur) is editable and the key (nom) is fixed, what I need to do is the above input field of parameters in JSON will be updated each time the below values (valeur) is changed

so input Parameters will get update just the values in JSON format which are modified below.

The input field parameters will be saved in the DB as JSON format like in the image

Comment: your goal is quite unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain an object and on an event (say a submit button), pick the values of the textboxes and add to the object. Use JSON.stringify to add that to the hidden textbox.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2hv2K/1/***

```
var obj = {};  // maintain an object
$("#btn").on("click", function() { // on an event, say a button click
    obj[$("#name").val()] = $("#value").val(); // add the values to the object
    $("#result").val(JSON.stringify(obj)); // stringify and put in the hidden field
});
```

**Edit (based on Op's comment):**

If you want to update the object itself, change the handler accordingly:

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/C63tW/2/***

```
var obj = {}; 
$("input#name, input#value").on("change", function() { // handle change event
    obj["reference"] = $("#name").val(); // update reference property
    obj["hotel-id"] = $("#value").val(); // update hotel-id property
    $("#result").val(JSON.stringify(obj)); // update the result field
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but sorry as I didnt state it correctly, could you please see the update of my question above, thanks

Comment: So what is the problem? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/C63tW/2/. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Your answer is great, thank you! Can I ask you one more thing if the reference and hotel_id are not fixed, can we get them from the data that is already in input parameters and parse the keys from JSON to get the key and set it to obj["key"] dynamically? Thanks

Comment: (1) *..data that is already in input parameters..*: I don't understand this, please explain clearly. (2) please change the title of your question. it is very confusing. it is perhaps the reason why people are closing your question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have just figure out that each row in the table of my example, they are looped by one for-each loop, so the number of line of key and value are not fixed, Is there anyway that I can go through the data of html table and convert them into JSON format? This is my html table : http://notepad.cc/share/dKV5hEKGIu

Comment: In that case, create an array and iterate thru the rows creating objects and adding them to the array.

Comment: I think that I can embed C# code in the cshtml ?